# Open a json file in a FTP using ftplib

Tags: python, ftplib

from our project, we are required to use ftplib module. I'm using ftplib to read the content of the json file in the FTP but it shows an error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.json'
Here's the simple code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
    
networkconnect = 'ftp.test123.com'
usern = '123'
pwconnect = 'test123'

ftp = FTP(networkconnect, usern, pwconnect)
ftp.cwd('/testpath')
with open('test.json', 'r') as j:
    json_data = json.load(j)
```

I've tried to use other module like ftputil and it opens the json file

Here the for example:

```
import ftputil

networkconnect = 'ftp.test123.com'
usern = '123'
pwconnect = 'test123'

test_host = ftputil.FTPHost(networkconnect, usern, pwconnect)
test_host.chdir('/testpath')
with test_host.open('test.json', 'r') as j:
    json_data = json.load(j)
```

But since I'm required to use ftplib, I want to know if there are any workaround in order to open a json file in an ftp using ftplib?

Thank you guys in advance

Comment: hi, yes it should be in quotes. My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way: Frist download file to local and next try open it.

```
currentDirectory = os.getcwd()
save_directory = os.path.join(currentDirectory, 'file.json') 

def download():
    try:
        ftp = ftplib.FTP('host', 'login', 'pass')
        files = ftp.nlst()
        filename = files[0] # get first file

        ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename, open(save_directory, 'wb').write)
        ftp.close()

        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False

if download():
   with open(save_directory, 'r') as j:
    json_data = json.load(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this running on a Raspberry Pi 2B. It doesn't touch the local file system. It is Python 2.x and I have stripped it down to the basics. The remote file content is copied to local RAM so beware of memory limitations against the source file size. It works just fine on my 23K file. Only got it to work on FTP (not SFTP).

```
# Comments: Read JSON stream from FTP.
import json
import ftplib, StringIO

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ftpsite = 'ftp.yoursite.com'
    ftplogin = 'yourlogin'
    ftppsw = 'yourpassword'
    ftpfilename = 'yourfile.json'
    print('ftp {ftplogin}@{ftpsite}'.format(ftpsite=ftpsite,ftplogin=ftplogin))
    print('retr {ftpfilename}'.format(ftpfilename=ftpfilename))

    ftp=ftplib.FTP(ftpsite,ftplogin,ftppsw)
    r = StringIO.StringIO()
    ftp.retrbinary('retr ' + ftpfilename,r.write)
    response = r.getvalue()
    r.close()
    ftp.quit()

    parsed_json = json.loads(response)
    print parsed_json
```